# Could not create object from service provider - Registering service using Dependency Injection

Tags: pipelines, dependency-injection

I have created an ItemNotFoundResolver and injected it after ItemResolver pipeline as follows :

```
public class ItemNotFoundResolver : HttpRequestProcessor {
private readonly ISitecoreEntityService _entityService;
public ItemNotFoundResolver(ISitecoreEntityService entityService)
{
   _entityService = entityService;
}
//code logic here to call a method from the SitecoreEntityService
```

The Patch file is as follows :

```
<httpRequestBegin>
<processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="TestProject.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemNotFoundResolver, TestProject.Feature.ErrorHandling" resolve="true"/>
```

In  Project TestProject.Foundation.ORM
Have created an entity service and registered the same

```
public class SitecoreEntityService : ISitecoreEntityService
{
    protected readonly ISitecoreService _service;
    protected readonly IMvcContext _mvcContext;
    protected readonly IRequestContext _requestContext;
    public SitecoreEntityService(ISitecoreService service, IMvcContext mvcContext, IRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Condition.Requires<ISitecoreService>(service).IsNotNull("ISitecoreService could not be null");
        Condition.Requires<IMvcContext>(mvcContext).IsNotNull("IMvcContext could not be null");
        Condition.Requires<IRequestContext>(requestContext).IsNotNull("IRequestContext could not be null");

        _service = service;
        _mvcContext = mvcContext;
        _requestContext = requestContext;
    }
```

In RegisterContainer.cs

```
public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISitecoreService>(provider =>
            Sitecore.Context.Database.Name.ToLower() == "core" ? new SitecoreService("master") : new SitecoreService(Sitecore.Context.Database));
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IRequestContext, RequestContext>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IMvcContext, MvcContext>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IGlassHtml, GlassHtml>();
    }
```

While I am trying to install a package through UpdateInstallationWizard, I am getting the following error in logs, while the last step (installation) is getting executed. and then it fails :

3052 20:30:51 ERROR Application error.
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException
Message: Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: 
< processor type="TestProject.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemNotFoundResolver, TestProject.Feature.ErrorHandling" resolve="true" patch:source="TestProject.Feature.ErrorHandling.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnPostAuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs )
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: TestProject.Foundation.ORM
   at TestProject.Foundation.ORM.DI.RegisterContainer.<>c.b__0_0(IServiceProvider provider) in C:\Projects\TestProject\src\Foundation\ORM\code\DI\RegisterContainer.cs:line 16
   at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)

Anyone have idea on why this error is shown. Am I missing something. 
Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sitecore.Context.Database` is `null` at the time when the `ISitecoreSevice` type is being injected. A simple null-check should probably solve this.

```
public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISitecoreService>(provider =>
    {
        var databaseName = Sitecore.Context.Database?.Name.ToLower();
        if (databaseName == null || databaseName == "core")
            return new SitecoreService("master");
        return new SitecoreService(Sitecore.Context.Database);
    });
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<IRequestContext, RequestContext>();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<IMvcContext, MvcContext>();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<IGlassHtml, GlassHtml>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the configurator?

Follow the "**Service registration**" section at https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/dependency_injection

[image]

Comment: Yes I have registered it
 <services>
      <configurator type="TestProject.Foundation.ORM.DI.RegisterContainer, TestProject.Foundation.ORM" />
    </services>